# Manually triggering get request gives different response then when made through whole application

Tags: json, rest, http, backend

There is a website and I want to access their backend api. I found a request which gives me json response, but when I change some parameters in the url, response is not changing, it's the same. I am not sure about the other parameters, but this one parameter that I want to use should change the response, but it's not.

Furthermore, when I monitor network tab in developer tools in chrome, and I send the request for the whole website, request that I want to use is listed and the response has the data I want, but when I copy that URL and send the request myself (isolated from the website) I am getting different response.

I've tried with two different locations over VPN and clearing chrome cache and it didn't work. Is there a way for this request to give the same response when caught while whole website is loading and when triggered manually?

Comment: Yes. You can, for example, send a different response whether the "Referer" is "https://example.com" or something else.

Comment: @MadWard Making a `Referer` the same didn't work

Comment: @MadWard But changing `x-locale` header worked! Thanks anyway, you got me thinking in a right direction. Post an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by setting the appropriate request header. There was a request header that changed the api response.